# SQL Query gives missing parenthesis error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been working on this for a few days and cannot figure out where the error is. The query is:

```
Select distinct p.PkgID, p.PkgName, p.PkgCost, c.CustFName || ' ' || c.CustLName as   "CUSTOMERNAME" 
FROM Subscription s, Package p, Customer c
WHERE p.PkgID = s.PkgID
AND c.CustID = s.CustID     
AND to_date 
 (s.StartDate, 'Mon DD, YYYY')=
to_date 
 (&StartDate, 'Mon DD, YYYY')
ORDER BY p.PkgID;
```

I keep getting:

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>       00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis".

I cannot find the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is what the table and insert statement looks like.

```
CREATE TABLE SUBSCRIPTION
(
SubID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT SUBSCRIPTION_SubID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
EndDate DATE NOT NULL,
CustID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,   
PkgID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL  
 );

ALTER TABLE SUBSCRIPTION ADD CONSTRAINT SUBSCRIPTION_CustID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CustID)     REFERENCES CUSTOMER (CustID);
ALTER TABLE SUBSCRIPTION ADD CONSTRAINT SUBSCRIPTION_PkgID_FK FOREIGN KEY (PkgID) REFERENCES PACKAGE (PkgID);

INSERT INTO SUBSCRIPTION
VALUES (010, to_date('Jan 01, 2010 11:30','Mon DD, YYYY hh24:mi'), to_date('Jan 01,   2013 14:30','Mon DD, YYYY hh24:mi'), 00001, 10101);
INSERT INTO SUBSCRIPTION
VALUES (015,to_date('Mar 01, 2012 17:00','Mon DD, YYYY hh24:mi'), to_date('Dec 05, 2012 17:00','Mon DD, YYYY hh24:mi'), 00002, 20202);
```

As a side note, I did try it this way as well:

```
Select distinct p.PkgID, p.PkgName, p.PkgCost, c.CustFName || ' ' || c.CustLName as   "CUSTOMERNAME" 
FROM Subscription s
        Left OUTER JOIN Package p on p.PkgID = s.PkgID
    Left OUTER JOIN Customer c on c.CustID = s.CustID       
WHERE to_date (s.StartDate, 'Mon DD, YYYY')=
to_date (&StartDate, 'Mon DD, YYYY')    
ORDER BY p.PkgID;
```

Comment: What is the datatype of s.startdate?

Comment: Could you please provide the code that creates the table and inserts some data in it?

Comment: S.StartDate is a Date.

Comment: @Ben, wow. Honestly I don't even remember changing the title. I totally agree with you. My mistake on that big time!

Comment: While not central to the discussion, you should really be using ANSI-92 SQL JOIN syntax.

Comment: @Ben, thanks for your help. Thanks to everyone for their help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input to `TO_DATE()` is two strings; even though you're using SQL*Plus substitution variables, you still need to enforce this.

Change

```
AND to_date(s.StartDate, 'Mon DD, YYYY') = to_date(&StartDate, 'Mon DD, YYYY')
```

to

```
AND to_date(s.StartDate, 'Mon DD, YYYY') = to_date('&StartDate', 'Mon DD, YYYY')
```

Are you sure `s.StartDate` is a character in this format? It sounds like it's already a date (I hope), in which case you don't need the `TO_DATE()` but it might be worth using [`TRUNC()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions220.htm#SQLRF06151) on the date to remove the time portion.

---

To edit my answer based on the comments I don't believe you've changed this in the correct way. It should be:

```
AND trunc(s.StartDate) = to_date('&StartDate', 'Mon DD, YYYY')
```

Note the `TRUNC()` and the `'` around `'&StartDate'`